# Print Page functionality in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Anyone done this in MVC? any info would be great!.
Thanks.

Comment: What functionality exactly are you looking for? Print functionality is normally controlled by the browser, not server side code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get pretty far simply by including a print.css file for media type print.

Hide everything you don't want and include logical page breaks and demensions (inches, etc... actually format *more* correctly using the print.css override).

I have used a custom controller (or filter) to handle links using something like index.print instead of index.html, which simply overrides the master layout with a layout more suitable for printing, but I still feel that the alternate stylesheet is the best way to go.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

Answer (score 5):

Printing a page isn't really a matter for ASP .NET or MVC.  Printing is a client-side operation, and therefore can (and should) be done entirely in client-side code.  JavaScript has [a method call](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech2.shtml) for this:

```
window.print()
```

Comment: actually my question relates to handeling print page functionality on pages with url like this Http://www.somesite.com/news/?articleId=5. I'm not quite how to handle such situations.

Comment: @Shane Km: In that case I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.  Are you trying to print on the server?  Like, on a printer connected to the server?  If you're trying to print on the client then it's still a client-side operation.  No "URL" is necessary.  If it needs to be in a link then the link can be `javascript:window.print()`.